# Request to reopen question 581643 please

Tags: support, reopen-request, off-topic

I'd like to have my question reopened and the down votes removed. It was closed for being off topic. Its not. Read it, and you'll see it clearly has to do with Software and how its used. Closing a post with nothing more than a cookie cutter statement only makes this useful site less useful.

[Link to the Original Post](https://superuser.com/questions/581643/)

Comment: Given that a moderator read your question and closed it as off topic (after another user flagged it as off topic), this request should probably contain a bit more than just "*Read it, and you'll see it clearly has to do with Software and how its used*".

Comment: Please don't delete your requests. I did actually spend time reading your question and typing up an answer. If you don't want to read it, you can of course ignore it.

Comment: I closed it because I'm tired of of people jumping to conclusions of what I'm looking for and assuming for themselves what I need. I want to know how to send such emails. I explained that I already had Outlook but it wasn't working for me. I did ask for the name of another program that could help me do this but seems to have gone noticed. I also never asked how Microsoft uses. And I did include a screen shot in the original post.

Comment: Asking for alternatives or product recommendations is generally not encouraged. You're being vague about "the methods you've tried" and what those "key parts" are that get stripped out. You did include a screenshot, but just from an email that actually looks fine. What I meant is: Please show your source, how you expect it to look, how it looks when sent through Outlook, and ask what can be done about it, then we can work from that. As it stands, the question is not constructive, sorry. (Please ping users with @ if you want them to receive a notification, thanks.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you prefer, it could be closed as being not constructive, as we don't know what Microsoft is using and there's no objective definition of what "professionally looking" is.

It's a safe bet to say that all professional e-mail templates are hand-crafted and thoroughly tested on various e-mail clients to ensure that they look good. And they're all not sent out via Outlook anyway.

<sub>(No, it can't [import millions of contacts](https://superuser.com/questions/474177/importing-about-millions-of-contacts-into-outlook).)</sub>

If you wanted to ask how to stop Outlook from mangling with your previously created templates, that would—in my opinion—be a valid question to ask. But make sure you give a concrete example and provide screenshots, et cetera.